# Why doesn't my image display? (JAVA GUI)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

I am having a strange problem. 
Today I wrote my program on Linux and I typed an adress to the image and everything was fine. Somehow, when I am trying on Windows at home the image just won't display!(I updated the adress of course) 
How should I write the adress to the picture? Where in the program package should I put it?
I left the second adress unchanged, so you can get the idea.

As you can see, there is another problem as well. 
I need to display two images but I see only one. Which layout should I use, in order to display 2 images next to one another?

Sorry if my questions are very stupid, I am still a beginner :)

```
public class View extends JFrame {
    JPanel jp = new JPanel();
    JLabel jl = new JLabel();
    JPanel jg = new JPanel();
    JLabel jz = new JLabel();

    public View() {
        this.setTitle("Media");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel contentAll =  new JPanel();
        contentAll.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        //(...)  a pair of buttons here, not relevant I guess

        jl.setIcon(new ImageIcon("/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Chrysanthemum.jpeg")); ///Windows
        jp.add(jl);
        add(jp);

        jz.setIcon(new ImageIcon("/home/d/Downloads/chanel.jpg")); /// Linux
        jg.add(jz);
        add(jz);
        jg.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        this.pack();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd also suggest showing any errors that are showing.

Comment: Can you use the '/' seperator char on windows? You could try building the path using http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separatorChar

Comment: I am not getting any errors, the image just doesn't show. I guess the URL is wrong.

Comment: Set the layout first before adding anything to the container. Use ImageIO.read to the images to see if there are any issues with the images

Comment: Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )
That's what I get when I change the path.

Comment: Use File.separatorChar like I said in my first comment, or escape the backslash like "pathPart1\\pathPart2"

Comment: `"\\home\\d\\Downloads\\chanel.jpg"` try it that way

Comment: @Frakcool, this one works, the Windows one doesn't.
The easiest solution seems to be to put it in the package, but I don't know how to call it from there

Comment: Not sure but my guess is that ` ` (space) in: `"/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Chrysanthemum.jpeg"`, those spaces make some strange things. Try it in different folder w/o spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Its `Chrysanthemum.jpg` in Windows.** use `jpg` instead of `jpeg`.

append `C:` in Windows to make an absolute path.

```
new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Chrysanthemum.jpg");
```

---

--EDIT--

use absolute path in case of Windows.

```
String userHome = System.getProperty("user.home"); // C:/Users/USERNAME
String userPath = userHome.substring(0, userHome.lastIndexOf("\\")); // C:/Users
String fullPath = userPath + "/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Chrysanthemum.jpg";
```

Comment: This worked! Oh God, THANK YOU! You just saved me another 3 hours wondering why!

Comment: Good correction, the first answer was irrelevant ;) I knew it was the path.

Comment: @SujanSivagurunathan I just copied path from OP post and I got it.

Comment: @Braj Good catch. But your comment about appending `C:` is not entirely right. What if Windows's directories are installed on another drive (represented by a different char) or on a remote location ?

Comment: @SujanSivagurunathan I have added it in my last post. Let me update it.